# Div style change with animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Is it possible add an animation when changing the style.display of an div to none/block?

HTML:

```
 <label><input type="radio" name="All" id="all" onclick="onChange(this);" value="all" />All</label>
```

JS:

```
function onChange(vl){
    let a = String(vl.value);

    if (a=="all"){
     var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("prs");

    for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++)
    {
    divsToHide[i].style.display = "block";
    }
    }
 }
```

Comment: is it ok to use jQuery? then it is easy

Answer (score 0):

you means **fadeout** ?

```
.prs {
  transition: all 1s;     
  opacity: 1;
}

.prs.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

when you want to hide `.prs`,

change the class to operate the `style.display`

Comment: To jQuery, you can use `.animate()`.Take care the `callback` of `.animate()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't what you mean exactly but you can use jQuery's Toggle.
When you click the button the div will show & hide animated.

See my fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/leagz/8urn5qxh/1/

Comment: Yes that is perfect, but i cant use jQuery for this project so is it possible with JS?

Answer (score 0):

i was create only with in a pure java script .if you need some animation effect add some `class`

```js
var check ="";
function change(vl){
  
    let a = String(vl.checked);
 var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("prs");
    if ((vl.checked)&& (check == 0)){
    for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++)
    {
    divsToHide[i].style.display = "block";
    }
      check=1;
  
    }
else{
  vl.checked = false;
  check=0;
   for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++)
    {
    divsToHide[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  
  
  }
 }
```

```css
.prs{display:none;}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="All" id="all" onclick="change(this)" value="all" />All</label>
<div class="prs">hello</div>
<div class="prs">hello</div>
<div class="prs">hello</div>
```

***Animation with class***

```js
    var check ="";
    function change(vl){
      
        let a = String(vl.checked);
     var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("prs");
        if ((vl.checked)&& (check == 0)){
        for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++)
        {
        divsToHide[i].classList.toggle("show");
        }
          check=1;
      
        }
    else{
      vl.checked = false;
      check=0;
       for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++)
        {
        divsToHide[i].classList.toggle("show");
        }
      
      
      }
     }
```

```css
    .prs{opacity:0; width:0;height:0;}
    .show{width:200px;height:30px;border:1px solid red;display:block;opacity:1;}
    div{transition:all 0.3s ease-in;position:relative;}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="All" id="all" onclick="change(this)" value="all" />All</label>
    <div class="prs" >hello</div>
    <div class="prs">hello</div>
    <div class="prs">hello</div>
```